# I want to create a relationship between list of suppliers and a single order in Hyperledger Composer

Tags: javascript, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger-composer

I have a transaction placeorder which takes list of supplier as input and creates an order.

```
transaction PlaceOrder 

    {
        o String orderId
        --> Consumer consumer
        o OrderDetails orderDetails
        --> Supplier[] supplier
        --> Commodity commodity
    }
```

The order is an asset having list of suppliers

```
asset Order identified by orderId {
    o String orderId
    o String orderName optional
    o OrderState state
    o OrderDetails orderDetails
    --> SupplyOrder[] supplyOrder
    --> Trader owner 
    --> Commodity commodity
    --> Consumer consumer
    --> Supplier[] supplier
    o Rating rating optional
}
```

This order is created when placeOrder transaction is called and that should create relationship between the list of suppliers.

For a single supplier I was using

```
order.supplier = factory.newRelationship(namespace, 'Supplier', placedOrder.supplier.getIdentifier());
```

but the above code is failing for list of suppliers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

two things may help

1. Is your transaction actually called 'placedOrder' (in your code) when you wrote "This order is created when placeOrder transaction is called " (just to check, it may well be).
2. because you've defined an array of relationships to Supplier, the `factory' statement should probably be:

```
     order.supplier = factory.newRelationship(namespace, 'Supplier', placedOrder.supplier[0].getIdentifier());
```

Comment: Yes the transaction is called placeOrder and placedOrder is the variable in which I get the values from the transaction.

I was trying to create a relation between array of Supplier in the order with array of Supplier in the transaction. I changed the array of Suppliers in the order to just Supplier and wrote the piece of code you provided in a loop. It worked for me. Thank you for your help.